# Qual diferença entre DropDownListFor e DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Qual diferença entre DropDownListFor e DropDownList?

E quando e qual usar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**DropdownList**

- Fracamente tipado (Run-time checking)
- Implementado no MVC 1
- Não suporta expressões lambda.
- Necessário especificar ID/Nome do elemento.

**DropDownListFor**

- Fortemente tipado (Compile time)
- Implementado no MVC 2
- Suporta expressões lambda.
- Basta especificar o tipo e a fonte de dados via ViewModel.

Answer (score 7):

Complementando a resposta do @Laerte:

O `DropDownList` pode ser usado para elementos fora do `Model`, como por exemplo no caso de o programador não querer implementar um `ViewModel` por precisar de apenas um campo do `form`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MeuUnicoCampoInteiro", MinhaVariavelSelectList)
```

A `Action` do `Controller` poderia ser feita simplesmente assim:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(int MeuUnicoCampoInteiro) { ... }
```

Já o `DropDownListFor` é a melhor opção para `Models` e `ViewModels`, considerando que o primeiro argumento é fortemente tipado, ou seja, o parâmetro precisa existir no `Model` ou `ViewModel` em questão.

`DropDownListFor` também é a opção mais adequada quando há aninhamento de classes. Por exemplo:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MinhaClassePai.MinhaClasseAninhada.MinhaPropertyInteira, MinhaVariavelSelectList, "Escolha uma opção...")
```

Answer (score 4):

Vamos pegar dois exemplos:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.EquipamentoId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Equipamentos, "Id", "Text")
)
```

e:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "EquipamentoId", 
    new SelectList(Model.Equipamentos, "Id", "Text")
)
```

> É óbvio que no segundo exemplo o nome da propriedade que você está
>   ligando ao dropdown é digitado como uma string. Isso significa que se
>   você decidir refatorar seu modelo e renomear esta propriedade, a
>   ferramenta de apoio que você deve estar utilizando não terá nenhuma
>   forma de detectar esta mudança e modificar automaticamente a string
>   que você digitou em, provavelmente, muitas views. Então você tem que,
>   manualmente, procurar e substituir em todo lugar que for utilizado
>   este helper fracamente tipado.
>
> Com o primeiro exemplo, por outro lado, nós estamos usando uma
>   expressão lambda fortemente tipada amarrando à propriedade do modelo
>   fornecido e então ferramentas serão capazes de renomear
>   automaticamente em todo lugar que for utilizado caso você decida
>   refatorar seu código. Também caso você decida precompilar suas views
>   você receberá um erro em tempo de compilação imediatamente apontando
>   para a view que precisa ser corrigida. Com o segundo exemplo você
>   (caso ideal) ou usuários de seu site (pior caso) receberá um erro em
>   tempo de execução quando eles visitarem esta view em particular.
>
> Helpers fortemente tipados foram introduzidos no ASP.NET MVC 2 e a
>   última vez que eu usei um tipo fracamente tipado foi em uma aplicação
>   em ASP.NET MVC 1 há muito tempo atrás.

Originalmente traduzido deste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8223513/1398758)